# Why do I need to specify $parent inside ngRepeat but not on the same element as ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <label ng-repeat="year in years" ng-class="{'btn-primary': year === selectedYear}" class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selectedYear" name="year" ng-value="year" />
    {{year}}
  </label>
</div>
```

In this code, I understand that I need to use `$parent` to bind to `$scope.selectedYear` because ngRepeat creates its own scope and `selectedYear` is a primitive which belongs to the parent scope.

What I don't understand is how `ng-class="{'btn-primary': year === selectedYear}` works.

Is the ngClass inside the ngRepeat's scope? If so, why does `selectedYear` not need `$parent` and if not, how can it use `year` which is inside the ngRepeat's scope?

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    $scope.selectedYear = $scope.currentYear;
    $scope.years = [$scope.currentYear - 1, $scope.currentYear, $scope.currentYear + 1];
  });
```

```css
body > div {
  padding: 15px;
}

.btn-group > label > input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">

  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <label ng-repeat="year in years" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-primary': year === selectedYear}">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selectedYear" name="year" ng-value="year" />
      {{year}}
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <br/>
  <br/>
  
  Selected year: {{selectedYear}}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question

```
Is the ngClass inside the ngRepeat's scope?
```

Since ng-repeat and ng-class are present on the same element, the order of execution is determined by the `priority` of each directive. The priority of ng-repeat is 1000 and that of ng-class is 0 which means the order of execution should ideally be

```
1) Compile of ng-repeat
2) compile of ng-class 
3) link of ng-repeat 
4) link of ng-class
```

according to my understanding, since ng-class gets linked first (where scope is attached), you don't have to use `$parent.selectedYear`.

I could be wrong but this is my understanding. Hope it might be of some help.

**EDIT**

After reading the code for ng-class and ng-repeat. Had a few corrections/changes to be added

Firstly, neither ng-class nor ng-repeat creates isolated scope.

Secondly, the order of execution that i mentioned was not accurate. The order should be

```
1) compile of ng-repeat
2) link of ng-repeat
3) link of ng-class (ng-class doesn't have compile)
```

This is because ng-repeat uses $watchCollection in its link function which updates the scope async using a `setTimeout`.

Now during the link phase of ng-repeat, it loops through the array and uses the transclude function to attach scope to the template (which is the whole div with ng-repeat in this case.)
This would mean, all repeated elements will have a new scope which follows prototypical hierarchy. This would mean that you could access the properties attached to the scope (in this case, properties attached to scope in the controller) inside child scope (scope of ng-repeat).

Since ng-class again doesn't have isolated scope and doesn't create a new scope internally, the scope in ng-class should be the same as used in ng-repeat.

Any suggestions/modifications are much appreciated as i am no pro.

It would be great if you could attach a working plunker.

To answer *How do i use year in ng-class?*. If by `year` you mean the value entered in the text-box by the user, you could use it just the way you are using it and it should work.

Comment: Your answer is probably right except - "*You don't have to use $parent.selectedYear*".  That binding is inside the `ng-repeat`, and he is printing the primitive value outside `ng-repeat` why is it not required..?

Comment: Ya this seems correct, `ng-class` has the `ng-repeat` scope, since it doesn't have it's own `selectedYear` property it's read from the prototype chain. BTW OP has included a working stack snippet in question

Answer (score 2):

You could do it also without $parent reference. The problem is in scope inheritance. When you create child scope, all variables - both objects and primitive variables are in child scope with the same names as they were in parent. But when you change primitive variables inside child scope, they are changed only inside child scope.
There are a lot of information about scope inheritance in internet. For example there is good explanation: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes
What you could do to avoid such cases - always put your primitive variables, which you want to bind, inside objects (like in my code snippet below)

About your question -

> Is the ngClass inside the ngRepeat's scope

<s>I think, ngClass creates their own scope. This scope inherits parents scope's variables (ngRepeat's scope and your controller's scope). So, primitive variable selectedYear in ng-repeat's scope and in ng-class scope are not the same.</s> Not correct, see comments

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("controller", function($scope) {
     $scope.settings = {currentYear: new Date().getFullYear()};
     $scope.settings.selectedYear = $scope.settings.currentYear;
     $scope.settings.years = [$scope.settings.currentYear - 1, $scope.settings.currentYear, $scope.settings.currentYear + 1];
  });
```

```css
body > div {
  padding: 15px;
}

.btn-group > label > input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">

  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <label ng-repeat="year in settings.years" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-primary': year === settings.selectedYear}">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="settings.selectedYear" name="year" ng-value="year" />
    {{year}}
</label>
  </div>
  
  <br/>
  <br/>
  
  Selected year: {{settings.selectedYear}}

</div>
```

Comment: ngClass doesn't create new scope.

Comment: So, ngClass is definetly uses ngRepeat's item scope. But in this case, as I understand - how could ngClass use selectedYear, which must be inside ngRepeat's item's scope, while we change selectedYear, which is in parent's scope. My though is that AngularJS just search variables in parent scope, while we are not creating them in child scope (through ng-model or by coding inside controller or smth else)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the value from the parent scope without $parent due to the scope prototypical inheritance.

For ng-model you have to use `$parent` to refer the parent scope directly because `ng-model` uses two-way binding - otherwise the new value would be set to the child scope instead of parent because selectedYear is primitive.

Comment: Did you expand and see his full code snippet? This is what he is doing, he knows this already and that's not his question. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37065034/2333214) is the answer to question.